# Need help changing a method from recursive to iterative

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack, iteration

I'm working on a program that will fix data corruption given the data and the hash of the correct data. It starts to get slow after about 4 or 5 bits are corrupted even when only dealing with only a few bytes of data, so I thought I would make it iterative instead of recursive. After doing some research, I found that I could use a stack to do so. I'm currently having trouble with finding the correct place to pop the variables off of the stack. Here's the original method.

```
private static void fixFile(byte[] data, byte[] hash, byte[] correctHash, MessageDigest hasher, long depth)
{
    int len = data.length;
    outer: for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        byte origVal = data[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte) (data[i] ^ (1 << j));

            if(depth > 1)
                fixFile(data, hash, correctHash, hasher, depth - 1);
            hash = hasher.digest(data);

            if(!Arrays.equals(correctHash, hash))
                data[i] = origVal;
            else
                break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the modified method where I tried to make it iterative.

```
private static void fixFile(byte[] data, byte[] hash, byte[] correctHash, MessageDigest hasher, long depth)
{
    Stack stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    int len = data.length;
    outer: for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        byte origVal = data[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte) (data[i] ^ (1 << j));

            if(depth > 1)
            {
                stack.push(depth);
                stack.push(i);
                stack.push(j);
                depth--;
                i = -1;
                j = 0;
                continue outer;
            }
            else
            {
                // where do I put this to make it work.
                j = stack.pop();
                i = stack.pop();
                depth = stack.pop();
            }
            hash = hasher.digest(data);

            if(!Arrays.equals(correctHash, hash))
                data[i] = origVal;
            else
                break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are sure that it will actually help? If it is slow even for a small number of bits, it looks like something is wrong with the algorithm, not implementation details.

Comment: I think it's slow with small numbers of bits because it needs to recalculate the hash every time it changes a bit. Could the hashing algorithm be what's causing most of the slowness? I'm using md5 when testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your recursive approach is ideal for this problem and all the time will be being spent in the digest function.

However, when you are fixing depth bits you can get a factorial(depth) improvement in the speed of the program. (So for 6 bits this will make the program go 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720 times faster.)

The issue is that your current code currently toggles depth bits in your data, but in any order.  i.e. when it toggles three bits it will try toggling bits 1,2,3 and 2,1,3 and 3,1,2 and 3,2,1 and 1,3,2 and 2,3,1 (amongst many other choices).  Note that in each of these cases exactly the same 3 bits are toggled so there is no point testing them all.

You can fix this by passing additional parameters to your code saying where the last bit was toggled (i.e. pass in i and j as i_base and j_base), and then only allow your code to toggle new bits if they are at a later position in the data (i.e. if i>i_base || (i==i_base && j>j_base)).